# How to translate "any" in this context?

Tags: grammaire

How would you translate the any in

> It's not part of anything

In French?

Would you say

> Ce ne fait pas partie de quelque chose
>
> Ce ne fait pas partie d'une chose
>
> Ce ne fait pas partie de rien

Or

> Ce ne fait partie de rien

Also, in this context:

"He's not a member of any group"

> Il n'est pas membre d'un groupe
>
> Il n'est membre d'aucun groupe

Which one would you use?

Comment: @Master D.C perfectly answered the question. But I would add that "Ce" is not valid in this case, you should instead use "ça" (hard to capitalize) or "Cela".

We expect "ce" to be used before a noun as "Ce manège" or before an adjective "Ce beau manège".

Comment: what about "quoi que ce soit" ?

Comment: @Random 'Ça ne fait pas partie de quoi que ce soit'.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps That's what I'm talking about, indeed, but none talked about it in answers...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1**- It's not part of anything = Ça ne fait partie de rien

In this example, the anything describe what he is not part of so "de rien" is a very valid option. "de quelque chose" is also accepted but could depend on the sentences.

**2**- He's not a member of any group = Il n'est membre d'aucun groupe

In this example the "d'aucun groupe" describe the fact that he is not part of any group at all. The "d'un groupe" means more something like: he is not part of a group. Which is somewhat different.

Comment: Nice you corrected the two mistakes.

Comment: Yeah my bad. I was using my phone and forgot to correct it. Thank for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Personnaly I would have said :

> Ce ne fait partie de rien

Because the double negation of "Ce ne fait pas partie de rien" makes it akward imo.

> Ça ne fait partie de rien

even sounds more natural…

Verboslier :

"Cela ne fait pas partie de quoi que ce soit"

Comment: Quoi que ce soit can be translated as anything in the rien sense?

Comment: Il n'aime pas quoi que ce soit?

Comment: @BlobGod : that's grammatically correct but everyone would rather say : "Il n’aime rien" (or "Il aime rien", there the negation doesn't really matter…) ;)

Comment: > Quoi que ce soit can be translated as anything in the rien sense?

Yes. "He doesn’t know anything" → "Il ne connait pas quoi que ce soit", but in this case : "Il ne connait rien" is far more fluent…

Comment: "Ce" is not a valid subject for a sentence, your second example doesn't work.

Comment: Is this very phrase, the subject is "Ce qui", not "Ce".

Comment: @AnneAunyme OK, got it, thx.